# Woher kommt das g in „Kopenhagen“? Why is there a g in “Copenhagen”?

Tags: etymology, place-name

Der zweite Wortteil des dänischen Namens *København* bedeutet, wie man auch leicht errät, *Hafen*, und in der Tat ist der schwedische Name *Köpenhamn*, wobei *hamn* das schwedische Wort für *Hafen* ist.

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopenhagen#Name_der_Stadt) entnimmt man, dass der dänische Name im Mittelalter *Køpmannæhafn* war, was *Kaufmannshafen* bedeutet, und dieser im isländischen *Kaupmannahöfn* erhalten ist.

Wann und warum ist aus dem *f* im Namen in der deutschen und anderen Sprachen ein *g* geworden? Gibt oder gab es eine germanische Sprache, in der das *f* in Hafen zu einem *g* geworden ist? Oder ist der Name den Umweg über eine nicht germanische Sprache gegangen, für deren Sprecher das *hafn* keine Bedeutung hatte? Oder war es schlicht ein [Missverständnis](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hag#Andere_Sprachen), eine Verwechslung von *Hafen* und *Hag*?

Oops, I have only now realized that I have asked in German, and since this question actually also applies to the English language, here is an
**English summary**:

The *havn* in *København* means *harbour* and is cognate with *haven*. The name comes from the older name *Køpmannæhafn*. So, whence the *g* in *Copenhagen*?

**Addendum.**
A related specific question is: Is or was there a low German language/dialect in which the word for (New High German) *Hafen* is *Hagen* or similar? See page 15 of [Stuhl](http://warburg01.cch.kcl.ac.uk/pdf/bkg210b2415478.pdf) for related claims.

Comment: According to the en.wikipedia the English name is derived from Low German. Still, that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Vielleicht hatte der Ostseesturmwind so laut geheult, dass die Germanen *hagen* statt *havn* verstanden haben...

Comment: @Em1: I think that'd be unrelated, though. See: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hag

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: meiner Meinung nach, könnte dies mit früherer Aussprache zu tun haben. Würde man die aktuelle isländische Aussprache bspw. ins Deutsche übertragen, käme "Höpp" (mit stummem "n") heraus bei "Höfn" (für Hafen). Die Verschiebung von a zu ö ist dabei im Isländischen grammatikalisch belegbar. Bspw: amma (Oma) -> ömmu (Oma, also im Akkusativ). Aber ein Mißverständnis klingt am logischsten.

Comment: Im heutigen Dänisch ist ja auch kein [f] oder [v] mehr in der Aussprache, wobei ich nicht weiß, seit wann. Genausowenig wie im Schwedischen. Von daher könnte ich mir eine Umbildung in das bekannte _-hagen_ grundsätzlich gut vorstellen.

Comment: Those are all useful comments. I will think about it some more and possibly edit the question a bit, since I was not really aware of the meaning of the word “Hag” when I started formulating the question.  I still feel that there are open questions, especially since I suppose that the meaning of *hafn/havn* was never lost in the Danish name, Danish was a language accessible to German speakers, and the German words *Hafen* and *Hagen* were always distinct.

Comment: @falkb: Du meinst, die hamm dat falsch verstann?

Comment: A friend has pointed me to page 15, and there in particular the second footnote of http://warburg01.cch.kcl.ac.uk/pdf/bkg210b2415478.pdf. In case that someone wants to follow that lead.

Comment: Na ja. Das Buch verfolgt eher die Pippi-Langstrumpf-Strategie; ex Germania lux.

Comment: Ich habe bei dem Buch nur auf die eine Seite geschaut, und mir fehlen Fachkenntnisse. Also gut möglich, dass das nicht Hand und Fuß hat.

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: have you read http://www.cosmiq.de/qa/show/2091648/Warum-heisst-die-Stadt-K-benhavn-auf-deutsch-eigentlich-Kopenhagen-und-nicht-Kopenhafen/ ? They didn't find an answer either.

Comment: @SchcS, thanks. I had not seen that, but I can hardly imagine less knowledgable answers.

Comment: has it to be "haven"?
why not "hagen", which is a old german word with the following meaning: fenced, enclosed area, plot, village, redoubt, castle, rampart

Answer (score 7):

Es ist hier wichtig zu wissen, dass das F auf altnordisch, isländisch und altdänisch im Wortinneren immer für [v] steht (außer vor s und t wo es tatsächlich [f] repräsentiert). Die Aussprache von -havn war also niemals mit [f], sondern ursprünglich mit [v].

Auf schwedisch ist aus /vn/ /mn/ entstanden - vielleicht via *[bn] (wie im heutigen Isländischen) so wie die oben zitierten Schreibweisen andeuten. Aber ich halte es für sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass ein schwedisches *[bn] als [gn] aufgefasst worden sein kann - erkenne keine Parallele. Und überhaupt hat Schwedisch ja mit der Sache nicht so viel zu tun. Schweden war damals weit weg, als die Schonen dänisch waren, und soweit ich weiß, war/ist die schonische Aussprache mit [wn].

Man kann eigentlich nicht von einer "natürlichen" Aussprache von -havn reden. Was natürlich ist, kommt auf die Sprache und die Sprecher an. Man kann also nicht die Aussprache [hawn] als eine "indication of a disappeared sound" ansehen, was sie ja etymologisch auch nicht ist. Es gibt keinen Grund anzunehmen, dass es komplizierter als *[vn]>[wn] ist.

> "[haven] still exists but means "garden""

Dies verstehe ich leider nicht. Es handelt sich hier etymologisch um ein anderes Wort (siehe unten). Der Abschnitt "it should be a consequence of the confusion caused by the meeting of Old Norse with Low German" ist mir auch nicht ganz klar. Wieso ist es eine Konsequenz davon?

Also: altdänisch *[havn] hat sich irgendwann zu [hawn] verändert, was ja die heutige Aussprache ist. Wann es geschehen ist, ist äußerst schwierig zu wissen. Es kann ganz früh gewesen sein.

Es ist auch richtig, dass ein dänisches G im Wortinneren heute sowohl stumm sein kann als auch wie [j] oder [w] ausgesprochen werden kann, und dies ist auch der Fall für altdänisches gh, das eigentlich was anderes ist und heute mit j oder v (=[w]) geschrieben wird (übrigens: Das Wort "guttural" wird nicht von der Sprachwissenschaft gebraucht, daher ist mir hier die Bedeutung nicht ganz klar).

Altdänisch "haghæ", "eingehegtes Gelände" (also dasselbe Wort wie deutsch Hag, -hagen), heißt heute "have", "Garten", und die bestimmte Form ist "haven" ['ha:wən]. Es muss früher einen kurzen Vokal gehabt haben (sonst hätte sich gh nicht zu v, sondern zu j verändert), also einmal *['hawən], "das eingehegte Gelände".

Es ist natürlich eine Möglichkeit, dass dies die Aussprache von "das eingehegte Gelände" schon im Frühmittelalter war, und es ist auch eine Möglichkeit, dass die Hansekaufleute das dänische *[hawn] "Hafen" als das dänische *['hawən] "das eingehegte Gelände" aufgefasst haben, also deutsch Hag, -hagen. So kann es erklärt werden.

Ich halte es aber eigentlich für unwahrscheinlich. Plattdeutsch war ja damals die Lingua Franca; normalerweise konnten die reisenden Kaufleute kein dänisch, woher sollten sie also wissen, dass es auf dänisch die zwei fast ähnlichen Wörter gab - und dann falsch raten? Und falls sie mehr Kontakt mit den Einheimischen - unter ihnen sesshaften Deutschen - hatten, dann sollte das Missverständnis wohl schnell aufgeklärt werden (die Nordfriesen haben es z.B richtig verstanden: "huuwen" bedeutet Hafen).

Dazu ist die Stadt ja eine Hafenstadt; und dänisch war ja auch damals eine geschriebene Sprache. Schriftlich ist "Hafn" ja deutsch "Hafen" sehr ähnlich (aber auf Plattdeutsch war/ist es natürlich "Haven" - wie war damals die Aussprache?).

Dies sind also Argumente dafür, dass es eigentlich unwahrscheinlich ist, dass -hagen ein Missverständnis von Hafen ist, aber dass ist nur meine Einschätzung. Das Ortsnamenelement -hagen war ja im Frühmittelalter auf Deutsch sehr produktiv, was man daraus sieht, dass es in den östlichen Bundesländern sehr häufig ist, wo die deutsche Ostsiedlung damals statt fand.

> "Ein weiteres Indiz für eine damals möglicherweise ähnliche Aussprache von dänischen 'v' und unserem 'g' liefert auch die Entwicklung des Verbs "fliegen", das aus dem Althochdeutsch fliogan im Dänisch zu "flyve" wurde, währen in anderen Sprachen das 'g' entweder erhalten blieb, oder ganz verschwand (to fly)."

Also, dänisch kommt aus dem Altnordischen (fljuga) - und es ist richtig, dass hier g (altdänisch gh) sich zu [w] verändert hat (['fly:wə]), genau wie in haghæ>have. Trotzdem kann man wohl nicht sagen, dass [w] dem deutschen [g] ähnlicher ist als z.B. dem [v].

Meine Muttersprache ist Dänisch.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort! Ich werde sie später genauer lesen und dann sicherlich auch noch mehr Kommentare oder Fragen haben.

Comment: Also bleibt es weiterhin unklar, warum -hagen verwendet wird?

Comment: Ja, meine Konklusion ist eigentlich, dass mein Vorschlag oben nicht allzu wahrscheinlich ist, aber dass ich keine bessere kenne... :)

Answer (score 3):

Die dänisch-norwegische Schreibweise "København" enthält ein 'v', während andere Schreibweisen entweder keinen Buchstaben, oder ein 'g' aufweisen (nur im Isländischen findet sich ein 'f' wie in unserem *"Hafen"*):

> Som eksempler kan nævnes tysk og nederlandsk **Kopenhagen**, engelsk **Copenhagen**, fransk, portugisisk og spansk **Copenhague**, latin **Hafnia**, italiensk **Copenaghen**, svensk **Köpenhamn**, ungarsk **Koppenhága**, finsk **Kööpenhamina**, tjekkisk **Kodaň**, polsk **Kopenhaga**, russisk **Kопенга́ген** (Kopengagen) og islandsk **Kaupmannahöfn**. 
>   <sup>[Wikipedia](http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B8benhavns_navn)</sup>

Weitere Schreibweisen aus einem Kommentar: Färöisch (Keypmannahavn), Nord-Friesisch (Kopenhuuwen) oder Irisch (Cóbanhávan), Alt-Englisch (Cēapmannahæfen.

Interessant ist hier die Aussprache des dänischen Wortes *"Havn"* ([hau̯ˀn]), es fehlt hier anders als im Deutschen (*Hafen*) oder Englischen (*haven*) sowohl eine Betonung auf dem 'v' (bzw. 'f') als auch ein *-en* Suffix.

Man kann also vermuten, dass die Aussprache zumindest früher anders als die des deutschen  *Hafen* war, und es deshalb auch in allen anderen Sprachen nicht zur Ausbildung eines 'f' aus dem dänischen 'v' kam, sondern ein 'g' hier der Originalaussprache näher lag.

Ein weiteres Indiz für eine damals möglicherweise ähnliche Aussprache von dänischen 'v' und unserem 'g' liefert auch die Entwicklung des Verbs  "fliegen", das aus dem Althochdeutsch *fliogan* im Dänisch zu *"flyve"* wurde, währen in anderen Sprachen das 'g' entweder erhalten blieb, oder ganz verschwand (*to fly*).

Begünstigt wurde das vielleicht zumindeste im Deutschen auch dadurch, dass es eine Reihe von Ortschaften gibt, deren [etymologische Wurzel im *"Hag/Hagen"*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hag) liegt, und dass Hafenstädte in ihrer Endung dann immer mit *-en* Suffix gebildet wurden (z.B. Wilhelmshaven, Cuxhaven...).

Für eine damals gegenüber heute zumindes lokal andere Aussprachen von *"-hagen"* gibt es weitere Hinweise. So schreibt Grimm zur Etymologie von *Hain*:

> **HAIN** [...] schon frühe taucht für **hagen** [...] die form hain auf, die sich aus erweichung der gutturalis gebildet hat; [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH00887)

Dass *Hagen* auch *Hafen* bedeutet hat, ist nirgends belegt. Es erscheint mir auch wahrscheinlicher, dass der Ortsnamen nicht durch wörtliche Übersetzung gebildet wurde, sondern dass die Nachbildung des Klangs in der fremden Sprache damals führend war.

Comment: Überzeugt mich nicht so. Das moderne dänische Wort für Hafen ist auch _havn_, nicht _haven_; kurz gesagt benutzen die nordischen Sprachen ihr jeweiliges Wort für _Hafen_, Finnisch folgt 1:1 dem Schwedischen, und alle anderen Sprachen übernehmen das _Kopenhagen_ der Hanse (also Niederdeutsch).

Comment: Danke. Die dänische Aussprache zu der Zeit, als das Wort *Kopenhagen* entstanden ist, wäre interessant. Spekulation hilft da allerdings nicht viel, ebenso kann man spekulieren, dass das heute nicht gesprochene *v* damals bestimmt noch gesprochen wurde, warum wäre es sonst da? (Oder war damals im Dänischen noch ein *f* in dem Wort?) 

Die Existenz der Endung *-hagen* für Ortschaften ist sicher wichtig, aber Du weist ja auch darauf hin, dass wir ebenso *-haven* kennen, was die näherliegende Wahl gewesen wäre. Aber vielleicht sollte man dem einfach nicht zu viel Bedeutung beimessen.

Comment: Dass chirlu die Hanse erwähnt, ist gut, erklärt es doch, warum die niederdeutsche Namensvariante so viel Gewicht hatte.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: ich meine, dass das 'v' schon damals nicht als 'f', sondern eher wie ein 'u' gesprochen wurde,  siehe dazu auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6312/why-is-vater-spelt-with-v-when-it-is-pronounced-like-father

Comment: Ok, dann lass mich sehen, ob ich die Hypothese richtig verstanden habe: Die dänische Aussprache war damals näher an „-hagen“ als an „-hafen“, so dass die im niederdeutschen gebräuchliche Endung „-hagen“ benutzt wurde, obwohl die Bedeutung eine andere ist. Richtig so?

Comment: *6 obsolete comments removed* - @jarnbjo: habe Deine weiteren Schreibweisen noch eingebaut (die aber m.E. auch nicht helfen, wenn es darum geht, zu erklären, wo nun das 'g' herkommt).

Comment: Ihr baut hier ein riesen Kartenhaus auf, was umfällt, sobald mal einer in die Geschichtsbücher der Stadt reinschaut. Manchmal ist weniger mehr.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed remarkable that "Kopenhagen" obviously originates from the Low German of the Hansa, as their own word for "haven" was "hafn" or "hafen". I join the idea that their choice of name was based on the Danish pronunciation (in the late Middle Ages).

As further support I have found the old Swedish spellings of "hamn =haven" as "hampn" and "hambn" (1524, 1527) in the Dictionary of the Swedish Academy (SAOL). I guess that "mb/mp" reflects a sound that might have been similar to "g" in Danish, at least when heard by Hansa merchants.

Still another indication of a disappeared sound is the present Danish pronounciation of "havn" [haun], while the natural pronunciation [haven] still exists but means "garden". I have no idea, though, why this sound appeared (in Old Norse, "hofn"), but it should be a consequence of the confusion caused by the meeting of Old Norse with Low German (which dramatically influenced the Nordic languages).

Nowadays the pronounciation of "g" is a major problem for those learning Danish - it is silent or pronounced by various kinds of guttural sounds, often very difficult to hear for a foreigner. Thus, many Danish sounds may be understood as "g" - already in the Middle Ages, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Es wäre kurz gesagt denkbar, dass "Hafen" ein naheliegender Trugschluss gewesen ist (nun zwar nicht mehr).

Alternativ dachte ich zuerst an *Hain*, siehe auch @Takkat oben. Das bringt mich aber semantisch nicht weiter,

Eher würde ich versuchen einen Vergleich zu den *Angeln*, nahelegen und damit allerlei eckiger Worte. Das ist lautlich schwierig zu begründen, insoweit mir weder *Hag* noch *Haff* als solche bekannt sind. Zwar ist da PIE *h2e'k-, *Ecke*, auch in Ortsnamen, bspw. wohl *Schwarzenegg*, aber *av*, *ev* ist mir gänzlich fremd und wäre kaum darauf zurückzuführen. Soweit *Ang-* ungefähr als *Enge* gedeutet wird, fehlt mir ebenfalla das Gegenstück. Hilfreich ist der Ansatz aber trotzdem, wenngleich vorerst an der Ungewissheit anderer Namen scheiternd.

Denn graphemisch nahe bei En *tight* liegt *tough*, das verglichen wird mit "Middle Low German: tā, taie, tēge", "Low German: taa, taë, tage, taag", "German: zäh", wobei etwa "-> Norwegian Bokmål: tøff" als Entlehnung aus Englisch gilt (da hat ich mich grad so gefreut). Neuer Versuch:

Bei *Schlucht* (siehe da) findet sich ein Bezug zu *schl_f-*, sowie ein Verweis auf Analogie bei *Neffe*. Immer noch kein klares Bild.

Der beste Vergleich, den ich liefern kann, der aber scheinbar nicht zugespiitzt auf Ortsnamen übertragen wird wie etwa *Ecke*, das ist *eigen*, En *own*, auch nur da mir das Paar erst gestern vor die Flinte lief. Aber English hat doch auch *-hagen* in dem Namen.

Wenn das und die zahlreichen ähnlich gelegenen Antworten nicht befriedigen, wäre alternativ ein semantisches Calque denkbar, das strengen Lautgesetzen nicht zu folgen braucht; so auch en.wiktionary, jedoch ohne Deutung. Mich überrascht übrigens, dass *Hafen* Germanisch sein soll. Wie zu erwarten ist dessen Herleitung ungewiss.

Als dritte Alternative käme hinzu, dass der Name besonders alt sei und etliche Umwege nahm. Bei *Aachen* bspw. steht Latein *aquae*, neben PGem *ahwo (nein, das ist nicht *woder, das *-w schwindet, vgl. *blau*, *blewaz), da auch *agwjo, *awjo "floodplain, island" und daher wohl *Skaþinawjō "Scania, Scandinavia" -- das passt doch mal wie Faust auf's Auge (no pun intended); Dabei wäre vielleicht eher Calque im nordischen "Hafen" zu sehen. Das ist lautlich aber nicht weniger schwerfällig, um nicht zu sagen erheblich. Zur Urindogermanischen Ableitung *h₂ékʷeh₂ steht [wiktionary] "The roots *h₂ep- (“(body of) water”) and *h₁egʷʰ- (“drink”) are probably unrelated. ..." nur für unser Thema wäre es einfacher, wenn dem doch so wär. Sei's drum. Bemerke auch: "A connection to *h₁eḱ- (“swiftness, celerity”) has been proposed, in which case the semantic development would be "that which is swift" > "river" (as attested in Germanic) > "water" (as in Latin)" hinsichtlich *Ecke*, *He'k-mo s.o..

Wenn ich mich nur erinnern könnte, wo ich eine Wurzel *h-m-* in der Bedeutung "fügen" fand passend  zu *Heimdallr*, dem mythischen Schmied, würde ich das auch noch hier einmassieren.

Das Schwedische *hamn* lädt zudem Vergleiche zu Eng. *heaven* ein, da dies unsicher zu *Himmel* gestellt wird. Vergleich zu *Heim*, *Hof, Hoop*; zu Eng. *hoop* siehe en.wiktionary:

> From Middle English hoop, hoope, from Old English hōp (“mound, raised land; in combination, circular object”), from Proto-Germanic *hōpą (“bend, bow, arch”) (compare Saterland Frisian Houp (“hoop”), Dutch hoep (“hoop”), Old Norse hóp (“bay, inlet”)), from Proto-Indo-European *kāb- (“to bend”) (compare Lithuanian kabė (“hook”), Old Church Slavonic кѫпъ (kǫpŭ, “hill, island”)). More at camp.

Vergleiche denn *Hafen*:

> From Middle English haven, havene, from Old English hæfen (“haven; harbour; port”), from Proto-Germanic *habnō, *habanō (compare Dutch haven, German Hafen, Norwegian/Danish havn), from Proto-Germanic *habą (“sea”) (compare Old English hæf, Middle Low German haf, Old Norse haf (“sea”), German Haff (“bay or lagoon behind a spit”), **perhaps, in the sense of "heaving sea", etymologically identical with Old Norse haf (“heaving, lifting, uplift, elevation”), derived from Proto-Germanic *habjaną (“to lift, heave”)),** or from Proto-Indo-European *kh₂pnós (compare Old Irish cúan (“harbor, recess, haven”)).
>
> [*emphasis mine*]

Siehe weiterhin *Hügel*; aber auch *hook*, *Haken* hinsichtlich *to bend*.