# Was ist eine "qualifizierte Antwort"?

Tags: meaning

Was zeichnet eine qualifizierte Antwort aus?

Was wäre ein Beispiel einer qualifizierten Antwort? Wie sähe eine unqualifizierte Antwort aus?

Weder Duden noch Google haben weitergeholfen bei der Suche nach einer Erklärung.

Comment: Ich bin nicht in der Lage eine *qualifizierte, versierte und geeignete Antwort* zu geben, und hinterlasse stattdessen einfach einen *unqualifizierten, unpassenden Kommentar*: *«Hier steht irgendein Schwachsinn.»*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eine qualifizierte Antwort ist eine Beantwortung durch eine Person mit der notwendigen Qualifizierung, die für die Beantwortung notwendig ist. In anderen Worten: eine Antwort von einem, der Ahnung hat, bzw. eine Antwort mit inhaltlicher Qualität. Die notwendige Qualifizierung bzw. die inhaltliche Qualität wird auch mit durch die anvisierte Zielgruppe vorgegeben, da Antworten immer auch auf den Fragesteller zugeschnitten sein müssen.

Manchmal meint man auch mit *unqualifiziert*, dass mit der Antwort (meist provokativ) ein notwendiges Niveau unterschritten wurde.

Umgangssprachliche Synonyme für unqualifizierte Antworten sind Gefasel, Gelaber, Stuss, Blödsinn, hohle Phrasen dreschen usw.

Comment: Ein positives Bsp. ist http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7934/woher-kommt-das-g-in-kopenhagen-why-is-there-a-g-in-copenhagen (vorallem die Antwort von Troels!). Dagegen haben die Antworten von http://www.cosmiq.de/qa/show/2091648/Warum-heisst-die-Stadt-K-benhavn-auf-deutsch-eigentlich-Kopenhagen-und-nicht-Kopenhafen/ so gut wie keinen Wert.

Answer (score 0):

Eine allgemeingültige Antwort auf diese Frage ist praktisch nicht möglich; sie wäre so allgemein, dass sie zwar vielleicht qualifiziert, aber unnütz wäre. Versuchen wir es trotzdem:

Vorbedingung für eine qualifizierte Antwort ist es, die Frage und den Fragenden ernst zu nehmen und die Intention zu verstehen. Erst dann kann das Informationsbedürfnis (oder auch Kommunikationsbedürfnis) des Fragenden befriedigt werden. Lehne ich beispielsweise abends einsam am Tresen meiner Eckkneipe, und eine umwerfend attraktive Blondine haucht mir die Frage ins Ohr: "*Haben Sie vielleicht Feuer für mich, junger Mann*?", dann wäre die Antwort "*Nö.*" evtl. sowohl sachlich zutreffend als auch ehrlich, aber in diesem Kontext nicht sonderlich qualifiziert.

Eine qualifizierte Antwort passt also zur Frage; sie nimmt den Fragenden und sein Anliegen ernst; sie ist sachlich korrekt und der Situation angemessen; und sie umfasst, wenn geboten, auch eine Begründung. Wird man z.B. nach der aktuellen Uhrzeit gefragt, verlangt eine qualifizierte Antwort nicht zwingend auch die Angabe der Sekunde (sachliche Korrektheit, Angemessenheit); auch der Versuch einer Begründung der Antwort dürfte hier eher skurril wirken.

Und aus der qualifizierten wird eine endlich gute Antwort, wenn sie dem Fragenden ein Lächeln ins Gesicht zaubert.